# Typescript compiler (tsc) and relative path

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsc

I want to compile the file and its dependencies. My goal import dependencies using the relative path.

example in `/root/subfolder/myFile.ts`:

```
import { myFunction } from '~/functions'
```

tilde `~` should show that `myFunction` is from the root folder

```
root
|-- functions.ts
`-- subfolder
    `-- myFile.ts
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"baseUrl": "src", // must be the same as "rootDir"
"paths": {
  "~/*": ["./*"]
}
```

Comment: Please how can the complied JS have its path relative to the `dist` as its baseUrl

Because inside the complied JS it still shows `~/functions`